# Best approach for a large intranet structure with multiple nested applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.1, intranet

So on the current system (running off of the .net 3.5 framework) the way it was made was there is a project for the main intranet site. This page uses a dll to load the menu & layout. Then there are a bunch of separate applications (different solutions) that use this same dll to load the site structure and then get deployed as a new iis site. The menu has links to each of these applications and essentially it creates one large intranet site.

The idea is to recreate the intranet which I have been tasked with. I will be using .net core 2.1 and a mvvm (or mvc) structure. So my question is what is the best way to go about this? I am not totally convinced that the current system uses the best approach and I kinda want to get out of the dll hell that the current system uses (there are lots of dlls not just for the layout). As for the layout and its re-usability what is the best approach for this? Should there be separate solutions for each internal project and how would they reuse the site layout if so? Or should it be one HUGE solution with multiple projects? Or what other approaches could be recommended?

Comment: Your question is too broad, but in general, you want a Razor Class Library. You can put all your common controllers, views, and static resources there, and either do a project reference in solution or deploy it as a NuGet package to share with other solutions.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Sorry I didn't know how to really word it any better. Ya that is more or less what I was thinking but in that case all separate solutions (nested applications) would still be deployed as seperate sites in IIS. Is this correct to do this?

Comment: All application projects have to be deployed separately, regardless of whether they're in the same solution or different solutions. A solution is just for organization of related projects. Your apps will have a dependency on your RCL and it will be published with them, whether via project reference or package reference.